# Why is my modal close button not working?

Tags: javascript

I "made" a modal (got it from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal)). However, the button to close the modal just doesn't work. The event to click on any part the modal to close it does work though. I've spent hours on this and researched as much as I could but I just can't seem to find the issue.

```js
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
const closeModal = document.querySelector(".closeModal");

document.querySelector("#shortCircuit").onclick = function() {
  modal.setAttribute('style', 'display: block;');
}

closeModal.onclick = function() {
  modal.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target === modal) {
    modal.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.4);
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  margin: 15% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #878787;
  width: 80%;
}

.closeModal {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.closeModal:hover,
.closeModal:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexLayout">
  <div id="shortCircuit">
    <h1>Short-circuit</h1>
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <button class="closeModal">&times;</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any issues with the code. But can you provide the entire html file?

Comment: @samnupel The problem exists within the posted code - it’s reproduced in the snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your click on the X bubbles up the DOM and triggers the open modal code again on `<div id="shortCircuit">`. You can stop that with `e.stopPropagation();`

```js
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
const closeModal = document.querySelector(".closeModal");

document.querySelector("#shortCircuit").onclick = function() {
  modal.setAttribute('style', 'display: block;');
}

closeModal.onclick = function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  modal.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target === modal) {
    modal.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.4);
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  margin: 15% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #878787;
  width: 80%;
}

.closeModal {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.closeModal:hover,
.closeModal:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexLayout">
  <div id="shortCircuit">
    <h1>Short-circuit</h1>
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <button class="closeModal">&times;</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Do you have any article that I can read to understand better these sort of issues with the DOM?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is that it is closing the dialogue and then triggering the show dialog event. This is because the click event bubbles through every layer underneath the mouse. To stop this just change the code to this

```
closeModal.onclick = function(e) {
  modal.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```